# Arraylist search string but no output

Tags: c#, arraylist, output, string-search

Can anyone tell me, why I don't get any output with this on `buttonclick`?

```
string searchString = TextBox1.Text;
ArrayList personarraylist = new ArrayList();
foreach (Person a in personarraylist)
{
    if (searchString == Convert.ToString(a))
    {
         personarraylist.Add(a);
    }
}
ListBox1.DataSource = personarraylist;
```

EDIT:

Hi everybody, thanks for your input. I have a class for Person, and all data created on the pages is stored in a file: FileController.ReadFile(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Personfile.ser")); This is where I need my data from. I use a Filecontroller class to write and read (also update) to and from the file. But the Search function has just gotten the better part of me. (as a student the data handling in file was required, or I would have used a DB). Hope this clears my code up a little. And do I have to compare the search term to something e g firstName, or can it work through the whole file?

Comment: Based on your previous questions you have static person array and also ToString method override on person class so you can try `ListBox1.DataSource = personarraylist.Where(p => p.ToString().Contains(TextBox1.Text)).ToList();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a new array list and then immediately `foreach` over it.  Since you just created it there are no items in it, so the `foreach` does nothing.

Comment: Well spotted - only noticed that myself while editing. I suspect that's not *all* that's required though.

Comment: @JonSkeet That's certainly possible, but it's the only thing that we can *know* is wrong with the code given.

Comment: I'd say that adding to the same `ArrayList` that he's searching through is pretty much *known* to be wrong, isn't it? (It'll cause an exception if there are any matches...)

Comment: @JonSkeet It's a matter of what you consider the mistake to be.  Perhaps the mistake is that he meant to `foreach` over a different collection then that would be all that needs to change.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Um, you're looking in an *empty* `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList personarraylist = new ArrayList();
foreach (Person a in personarraylist)
{
    ...
}
```

That's never going to enter the body of the `ArrayList`. I suspect you meant something like:

```
ArrayList people = GetAllPeopleFromSomewhere();
foreach (Person a in people)
{
    ...
}
```

Additionally, even if you *did* have some values to look through, it's entirely possible that `Convert.ToString(a)` wouldn't return the searched-for value. Unless your `Person` class overrides `ToString()`, you'll just get the class name. It's more likely that you actually want something like:

```
if (a.FirstName == searchString)
```

(Or whatever property of `Person` you actually want to search for.)

Then, you're currently adding to the same `ArrayList` that you're searching through - that's not what you want. You might want something like:

```
ArrayList people = GetAllPeopleFromSomewhere();
ArrayList matches = new ArrayList();
foreach (Person a in people)
{
    if (a.FirstName == searchString)
    {
        matches.Add(a);
    }
}
```

I'd also suggest using generic collections, and ideally LINQ. For example, with LINQ your entire code could be converted to something like this:

```
ListBox1.DataSource = GetAllPeople().Where(p => p.FirstName == searchString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are converting the Person object to a string. You might want to be looking at an element within the Person object for the data you want to compare against.

Answer (score 0):

```
string searchString = TextBox1.Text;
ArrayList personarraylist = new ArrayList();
foreach (Person a in originalpersonarraylist)
{
    //Assuming that there is a Name property in Person Class.
    if (a.Name.StartsWith(searchString))
        personarraylist.Add(a);
}
ListBox1.DataSource = personarraylist;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill the personarraylist with values before commencing foreach loop.
Something like this should be more usful:

```
    string searchString = Textbox1.Text;
//Retrive the person data for some location
ArrayList personarraylist = getPersonData();
foreach (Person a in personarraylist)
{
    if (searchString.contains(a.ToString()))
    {
        personarraylist.Add(a);
    }
}
ListBox1.DataSource = personarraylist;
```

Answer (score 0):

Required operation can be completed in rather straightforward and efficient way using regular array (`string[]`) instead of `ArrayList`. The solution is outlined below:

1. Read the entire file as a single string and assign it to `string _tmp` var (use any object/methods that you are familiar with, for  e.g. `System.IO.StreamReader`)
2. Apply `Split()` method to get `string[]` array from `_tmp`:

   `string[] _arrPerson= _tmp.Split(string[] separator)`;
3. Populate `ListBox1` from that array _`arrPerson` based on a search condition that you have specified using `Items.Add()` method of `ListBox1`:

   for (int i=0; i<_arrPerson.Length;i++)
   {
   if (_arrPerson[i].Contains(searchString)) {ListBox1.Items.Add(_arrPerson[i]);}
   }

This code snippet should run much faster than all that variations utilizing `ArrayList`.

Hope this will help.
My Best, AB

PS: see MSDN [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) for details on String.Split() method